# Loading Data from Plist Delay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, core-data, plist

I'm trying program something very similar to iPhone's Clock application. In Clock.app, when you add a new World Clock, a modal view appears for searching and adding new cities. While I can get this functionality, I have a long delay before displaying the modal.

I've implemented the modal view, the search bar, and the tableview. I've created a plist with an array of dictionaries of over 1,000 cities and their corresponding states, like so:

```
<dict>
    <key>City</key>
    <string>Chicago</string>
    <key>State</key>
    <string>Illinois</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    ...
</dict>
```

My problem appears on the modal views's viewWillAppear when I parse the plist into an array of "City" objects using a for loop. The parsing and searching works, but this loop creates a long delay before the modal sides up.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe using CoreData, multiple threads, GCD? I'm a beginner, so I'm not sure what the best option is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its always better to do any long-running operation in the background.  On iOS there are a number of ways to do that.  If you are able to limit to iOS 4+, then dispatch queues are a great way to go.  Otherwise, you can go with an NSOperationQueue.

Comment: Went with GCD. Worked great and was really easy to implement: http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/27/a-simple-job-queue-with-grand-central-dispatch/